# Anyone knows what `cimg::exception_mode() = 0;` does?

Tags: c++

```
  const unsigned int omode = cimg::exception_mode();
  cimg::exception_mode() = 0;
```

Never see this kinda syntax before.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

exception mode might be returning a reference, and it is being set to 0. For example:

```
unsigned int& exception_mode() { return mode; };
```

So, the second line would be equivalent to:

```
void set_exception_mode( uint v ) { mode = v; };
```

BTW, it is really ugly!  I would avoid this kinda syntax as much as I could.

Answer (score 3):

The function is probably returning a reference to an `int`.

```
unsigned int exceptionMode; // Declared somewhere
// ...
unsigned int& cimg::exception_mode() { return exceptionMode; }
// ...
cimg::exception_mode() = 0;  // Equivalent to exceptionMode = 0;
```

This allows whatever is returned to act as an *l-value*. In this case, it's setting the referred `int` to zero.